# Is this a Hindu deity?

Tags: goddess, identification-request

Is this a Hindu Goddess?  If yes which one and what do they represent?

[image]

Comment: Could be some form of a demi-goddess. Like a nAga devata. Check on buddhism forums too. Could be one of their dakinis/goddesses. The art style, jewelry style and the shape of the figure indicate the drawing is likely from a buddhist culture.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: to me it looks like the snake curling around Shiva's throat after he drank the Eternal Poison.

Comment: Looks like a Thai engraving

Answer (score 5):

This looks more like a Thai goddess rather than an Indian/Hindu one. In fact it may not even be a goddess but just a dancing girl as this is a really popular pose from Thai traditional dancing as evident from the below image:

[image]

Generally it is shown for the **[kinnaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnara#Thailand)** who are half human-half bird divine beings in South east Asian mythologies especially Thailand:

[image]
[image]

BTW I found something similar to your pendant being advertised on ebay labeled as a Thai dancing goddess:

[image]
[image]

Most likely it is just a dancing girl or kinnari being advertised as a goddess.

Comment: BTW take a look at this chat conversation - https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38640?m=38048202#38048202 I tried hard to find but from Hinduism perspective the fig. is close to this form.

Comment: Well the posture is a little similar but doesnt seem to be the same if you notice the hands are not turned outwards like the image in the question.. looks like a Thai dancer to me especially because of the position of hands and legs.

Comment: Yes , but it looks like she is holding a pot in her right hand . Although not too clear :-)

Comment: Hmm looks like something shiny actually with the rays coming out :)